Long exact sequence of homotopy groups: connecting map and action of $\pi_1(B)$
Let $F \rightarrow E \rightarrow B$ be a fiber bundle, and let $\delta_n:\pi_n(B) \rightarrow \pi_{n-1}(F)$ be the connecting homomorphism in the associated long exact sequence of homotopy groups.
Question: Does $\delta_n$ interact with the action of $\pi_1(B)$ on $\pi_n(B)$ in any way?  That is, given $x \in \pi_n(B)$ and $\gamma \in \pi_1(B)$, is there any general relationship between $\delta_n(x)$ and $\delta_n(\gamma \cdot x)$?
I am especially interested in the case $n=2$.
I know that there is a monodromy homomorphism $\pi_1(B) \rightarrow \mathrm{Homeo}(F)/\mathrm{homotopy}$, which may be relevant, but this monodromy homomorphism need not preserve basepoints, so it doesn't necessarily induce an action of $\pi_1(B)$ on $\pi_{n-1}(F)$.

You might want to take a look at section 1.5. of May's & Ponton's "More Concise Algebraic Topology".

Maybe the right thing to say is this.
As you observe, we don't have an action of $\pi_1(B)$ on $\pi_{n-1}(F)$. But we do have an action of $\pi_1(E)$ on $\pi_{n-1}(F)$. And if $\gamma\in \pi_1(B)$ is the image of an element $\bar \gamma\in \pi_1(E)$ then I believe that
$$
\delta_n(\gamma\cdot x)=\bar\gamma\cdot \delta_n(x).
$$
